# Java compile error: symbol cannot be found

Tags: java, symbols

My assignment is this:

Create a Java program that satisfies the following requirements:

- Create a single Java source file named MaxScore.java
- Create a single class named MaxScore
- The MaxScore class has two methods:

  - main
  - maxScore

The maxScore method takes seven integer arguments
When called, the maxScore method returns the largest of the seven input arguments

The main method performs the following steps seven times:

- Write to STDOUT: Enter a score:
- Read from STDIN an integer value and store it in a new variable
- The main method calls maxScore with the seven integers obtained from
  STDIN
- The main method writes to STDOUT the maximum score in the following
  format: Maximum score is:

My main problem is that the symbol is not defined. I have tried this a bunch of times with no luck. I'm sure it's a fairly easy to fix problem but I could really appreciate some help.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MaxScore1{
public static void main(String[] args){ 
//establishes the main method first
int z = a,b,c,d,e,f,g; 

    z = maxScore(a,b,c,d,e,f,g); 

    Scanner foo = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    //repeating the code 7 times in order to get 7 integers that are the scores
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    a = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    b = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    c = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    d = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    e = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    f = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
    g = foo.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Maximum value returned by maxScore is " + z + "."); 

    }
public static int maxScore(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e,int f,int g){ 
//calling all the integers obtained earlier
    int x; 
    //establishing a base for the currentscore
    x = 0;
    //establishing the variable
    if (a > x){ 
    //a set of if statements to return the maximum value
        x = a;
        }
    if (b > x){
        x = b;
        }
    if (c > x){
        x = c;
        }
    if (d > x){
        x = d;
        }
    if (e > x){
        x = e;
        }
    if (f > x){
        x = f;
        }
    if (g > x){
        x = g;
        }
    return x; //returning the maximum value obtained.
    }
```

}

My errors are:

```
    MaxScore1.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    int z = a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
            ^
      symbol:   variable a
      location: class MaxScore1
     MaxScore1.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
            z = maxScore(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
                         ^
     symbol:   variable a
     location: class MaxScore1
    MaxScore1.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            a = foo.nextInt();
            ^
      symbol:   variable a
      location: class MaxScore1
     3 errors
```

Comment: Ignoring that you haven't declared those variables, trying to compute something *before* you've taken the input probably isn't going to work out.

Comment: [Have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) googling the error message? That should always be your first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your variables correctly `int z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g;` and calculate the max score only *after* you read in all the values.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly, It compiled perfectly. I am so sorry for such a newbie question. I am very new to programming. This help is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare your variables  like this
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g; 
Not in the way that you did it already.